# Prevent the user to go back to the React app after he leaves it

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a very simple `React` app:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-testing-routes-navigate-outside-g7ejr5

where I have 3 react pages: { `Page1`, `Page2`, `Page3` } and 1 html page: { `external.html` }.

I want to flow in the following way:

`Page1` → `Page2` → `Page3` → `external.html`

with the particularity that once the user leaves `Page3` and arrives to `external.html` he cannot go back to the `React` app at all.

Bear in mind that I don't have control over: `external.html` (3rd party website).

Is there any way to disable at all the back button and or the history when leaving `Page3`?

If you have any approach for this, please feel free to fork the project above and paste the new link here.

Thanks!

Comment: I would probably just use something like localStorage to track when someone is done. Then, before rendering the app in your index file, check if that localstorage key is set. If it's set, redirect to the external page

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways in which this can be handled -

Inside your `page3.jsx -> goToLink`

1. You can use `window.location.replace('external.html')`
   But this will only prevent the user to go back to page3, it will still allow going back to page2, and so on.
2. You can open your `external.html` using `window.open('external.html')`, but in this case you will need to figure out way to close current tab somehow. You can try using `window.close()`, but that usually gives this error/warning `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something is authorizing your user to access Pages 1, 2, and 3. You would need to track their session in some way regardless. How will you know when to call `window.location.replace`?

How will you know if its the same person, a different person, or the same person who closed the browser and manipulates his local storage or sends some contrived request that gives them access to your pages again. Some type of session tracking is 100% necessary if authorization/authentication is in play.

Best way I believe is use **JWTs**. Require the JWT for page 1, 2, and 3 then expire/remove it when the last page is left (also have it on a short expiration timer).

You don't need user logins or anything heavy duty to do this, just send them a JWT cookie once you deem them authorized to view the pages, and require it for access.